# Cupertino style showModalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I wanted to ask if there is any Cupertino style “showModalBottomSheet” available by default in Flutter? I’m designing the app for iOS and that’s one of the things I want to include for my “Add record” process of the app.

I would like to achieve this:

[image]

On iOS there is also animation tight to that where background screen is “zoomed out a bit”.

I would thought that it will be part of the Cupertino package but I haven’t found it there.

Appreciate any guidance/help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

use showCupertinoModalPopup,

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart' before using it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing - I didn't know about that to be honest. In this case I understand that I'll need to define my own animation that will make the background being zoomed, right?

Answer (score 0):

Modify this as your requirements

```
showBottomModalDialog({
        required BuildContext context,
        required bool isLight,
        required List<Widget> children,
      }) {
        showCupertinoModalPopup(
            barrierDismissible: false,
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext modalContext) => Container(
                height: Get.height * 0.90,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: isLight
                      ? LightThemeColors.white
                      : DarkThemeColors.cardBackground,
                  borderRadius:
                      const BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(25.0)),
                ),
                child: Material(
                    borderRadius:
                        const BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(25.0)),
                    color: isLight
                        ? LightThemeColors.white
                        : DarkThemeColors.cardBackground,
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, children: children))));
      }
```